# Is there max response length When Chrome data compression proxy enabled?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, proxy, compression, gzip

Is there max response length When Chrome data compression proxy enabled ?

I have HTML page with ajax call the response return a big text stream (~7000 chars).

I have compression configured on my IIS to compress static & dynamic content.

Few facts :

1. When the response greater then 4000 chars, the ajax response with :
   `error status=0 ,responseText="" readyState=0`
2. When I am reducing the response length the ajax call working great.
3. when I turn off the data compression proxy it works great.
4. the server return XML , I have checked it for sure ,there is no XML   format issue.
5. When I am open the site with the Chrome data compression proxy enabled on my local enviroment evry thing works fine - but this I guess becuase the proxy not working on local ip
6. No error on server.

What I have tried :

1. Change ajax call `(GET/POST)`
2. Set in ajax call `headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-transform' }`
3. set header on server response :

   Response.Cache.SetNoTransforms()  OR / AND
   Response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache") OR /AND
   Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform")

Outcome : the same error

Only short the response length to lower then 4000 chars  fix the problem
(it's nothing about the response content --> checked)

PLEASE HELP !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the tech lead for the Chrome compression proxy. There is a max length but it should be many megabytes, so I am surprised you are seeing this issue. If you can file a bug at crbug.com and include a netlog (from chrome://net-internals) and assign the bug to me (mdw at chromium dot org) that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey ,I will post the log...Can you please indicate the exact max length so I will be able to put this concern behind.Thanks

Comment: I believe the max response length that we currently support is 16MB.